# Is calling viewDidLoad in response to a settings view controller for a map kit radius a hack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I have a ViewController that shows a UIMapKit piece. All of the MapKit pieces are handled in viewDidLoad.  I also have a Settings View Controller that can change the radius of the loaded Map.

For the modal view I have set up a delegate to be called on the LocationsMapViewController. I am currently doing this by:

```
-(void) updateMapUI
{
  NSLog(@"here is my update in updateMapUI");
  //[self initWithCoordinate:self.coordinate locations:self.locations];
  //[self loadView];
  [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

But this seems kinda inelegant. Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? Or is this ok? My first time implementing something like this and just want some feedback.

thx

Comment: The answer is yes, but I'm trying to figure out exactly what you are trying to do so I can help you fix it. What I understand is that you are allowing the user to change some setting and then wanting to reconfigure things based on that change, is that right?

Comment: Y - basically, a zoom feature on the map that is persisted across other searches. Using MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coor, vals);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You shouldn't call this directly. Remember, you should be making a call to the superclass's `viewDidLoad` which could have unintended consequences. How about switching it around...

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self updateMapUI];
}

-(void) updateMapUI
{
  NSLog(@"here is my update in updateMapUI");
  //[self initWithCoordinate:self.coordinate locations:self.locations];
  //[self loadView];

  // Update your Map here

}
```

... and *please* tell me you're not calling `[self initWithCoordinate:self.coordinate locations:self.locations]` from within `viewDidLoad`!!!

Comment: no, not calling there. was just seeing what would happen. thx for answer on other part. In response, to what you said re [super viewDidLoad], isn't it possible that there are other elements that need to be called? Granted this is a vanilla MyViewController:UIViewController. Not trying to be argumentitive, just curious about best practices.

Comment: Any setup that is called once - put in viewDidLoad. Any that you might need to be called again - put in a separate method, then call that from viewDidLoad, and from wherever your updates get triggered.